# AJAX problems in Opencart

Tags: opencart

I have some problems with data which i send through AJAX 'get' method to a controller.

My AJAX code (in .tpl file) which selects the information from  list

```
<script>
     $('#category').on('change', function() {
            $.ajax({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'index.php?route=module/my_module&category_id='+this.value,

            }).done(function(data, Status){

            });
      });
</script>
```

I checked it on Ghrome Web tools, it works, i see the request.
My code in Controller:

```
 $this->load->model('catalog/product');
        $category_id = $this->request->get['category_id'];
        $this->data['product'] = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductsByCategoryId($category_id);

        $this->response->setOutput();
```

I can't see the variable $product in .tpl after the AJAX request.
What's the problem? I tried to make a special function in controller but it doesn't work.

**UPD:** 
New AJAX function:

```
 $('#category').on('change', function() {
        $.ajax({
      url: 'index.php?route=module/my_module/AjaxGetProduct&category_id=' + this.value,
      dataType: 'html',
      success: function(htmlText) {
        alert(htmlText);
        $('#product_summary').html(htmlText);
      },
      error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
      }
    });
  });
```

The model code is:

```
public function getProductsByCategoryId($category_id) {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product p LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category p2c ON (p.product_id = p2c.product_id) WHERE pd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' AND p2c.category_id = '" . (int)$category_id . "' ORDER BY pd.name ASC");

        return $query->rows;
    } 

    public function getProductDescriptions($product_id) {
        $product_description_data = array();

        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");

        foreach ($query->rows as $result) {
            $product_description_data[$result['language_id']] = array(
                'seo_title'        => $result['seo_title'],
                'seo_h1'           => $result['seo_h1'],
                'name'             => $result['name'],
                'description'      => $result['description'],
                'meta_keyword'     => $result['meta_keyword'],
                'meta_description' => $result['meta_description'],
                'tag'              => $result['tag']
            );
        }

        return $product_description_data;
    }
```

My updated function for AJAX request in Controller:

```
public function AjaxGetProduct(){
        if (isset($this->request->get['category_id'])) {
          $category_id = $this->request->get['category_id'];

          if ($category_id > 0) {
            //loading the AJAX
                $this->template = 'module/my_module.tpl';
                $this->load->model('catalog/product');
                $product = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($category_id);
                $data['product'] = $product;
                $this->response->setOutput($this->render());


          }
          else {
              echo "Error";          }
        } else {
            echo "Error";
        }
    }
```

When i try to alert the value of htmlText answer in AJAX success case, i see all of the template code in pop-up window: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like OC 1.5 and to get the results passed as json rather than through a template remove the `$this->template = 'module/my_module.tpl'` and change

```
$data['product'] = $product;
$this->response->setOutput($this->render());
```

to

```
$this->response->setOutput(json_encode($product));
```

Comment: I tried to change this.value to this.val() but first one works, i can see a request in Chrome webmaster tool.
I work with OC 1.5.

Comment: updated the answer, I didn't realise you were trying to get the products with ajax sorry

Comment: in the controller: 

$category_id = $this->request->get['category_id']; 

get['category_id'] - is the request parameter i'm sending through AJAX

Comment: Can we have a chat in Skype?))